# What's the technical name of this slotted type of RJ-45 connector?

Tags: layer1, lan

What's the name of the type of plug that has the little thing on the side that prevents it from fitting in regular 8P8C sockets?

Thanks!

[image: slotted rj-45 female]

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

That is a keyed connector, possibly an RJ-45S, suitable only for telephone systems.

In any case, an inline connector, such as this, is unsuitable for UTP LAN cabling.

Comment: keyed is the term I was looking for! thanks so much!

was actually trying to use it with a PoE camera, somehow I ended up with a box full of 25 and 50 foot cables of this. It wasn't working lol